# Creating a react typsecript package using rollup and getting module not found error. Is there anyone who encountered and knows the solution for it?

Tags: typescript, npm, package, rollup

I'm create a npm package using create-react-app typescript and configured using rollupconfig. When I try to import the build package in another app, I'm getting below error.

What I see in the browser..

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../include/modules.js' in 'path\dist'
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../include/action.js' in 'path\dist'
```